# sudo command not working despite sudoers file

Tags: debian, sudo, sudoers

I'm trying to use `sudo` command in Debian 9. For example `sudo apt install zsh` will ask the root password but does not accept it. I do indeed know the root password (I'm the only user of this machine) and I have added my 'meouser' to the sudo group.

```
root:~# cat /etc/group | grep sudo
sudo:x:27:meouser
```

I have edited `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo` and it has lines (should I show more of it?)

```
root:~# cat /etc/sudoers | grep -w sudo
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

But this is what happens:

```
meouser:~$ sudo apt install zsh

We trust you have (...etc removed the usual warning...)

[sudo] password for meouser: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for meouser: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for meouser: 
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

I have tried this several times, the problem is no way mistyping the password gazillion times. What I'm doing wrong? Advice appreciated. I have of course searched SOF but have not found this situation; in particular I have no problem with accessing the `/etc/sudoers` file itself.

Comment: Ask here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It _might_ be suitable for [sf] or [unix.se]: consult the Help Centre for the site before you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was embarrassingly easy one... thanks @user3469811 for the tip, here it is:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170894

As it turns out, I was stubbornly inputting the **root** password, not meouser's. (My mind was stuck on following the `su -` procedure.) On hindsight, it does request "password for **meouser**". Ah well once again I'm saved by the community.